# How do I lock a part of a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

I want to edit a mesh with the sculpt tool, but I don't want to sculpt a specific part of the mesh. How can I overcome this? Is there an option in Blender to do it?

(I'm using Blender 2.90.1)

Comment: Yes, there's a dedicated tool. Look for the masking brush.

Comment: Here's the masking brush that Carlo is referencing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/brr9e.png